# Tmux [exited] on startup

Tags: 13.10, gnome, tmux

I recently installed Tmux and became really glad for it. All of a sudden I though it would start throwing an error when I try to create a new session from within my terminal:

```
tmux new -s my-session
```

will cause the application to crash and only return

```
[exited]
```

and put the following on the next command line:

```
62;9;c
```

Being new to Tmux I have no idea how to fix this issue. Does anybody recognize this error and knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Removing

```
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"
```

from the configuration fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Seems to me as specific problem, Wasn't `62;9;c` the line & column index in configuration file where error raised?

Comment: Does this pinpoint the location in the config where it encountered an error?

Comment: I don't know, but I'm asking if you know? or you can confirm if so?

Comment: Just checked and the error occured on line 27, so nothing to go on from 62;9;c

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem, and the reason was that the shell path was wrong in my .tmux.conf

```
set -g default-shell /usr/local/bin/fish
```

It couldn't find the shell, so it crashed. You should probably check whether your default shell's path is correct.

Comment: your answer isn't clear... what is the correct path?

Comment: use the command ``which`` to locate where the file is, for example: ``which fish``

Comment: i had the exact same problem, moving from mac to ubuntu! with apt the correct path is probably '/usr/bin/fish'.

Answer (score 3):

First, I uninstalled tmux and removed its config file  `.tmux.conf`. The thing that worked for me was deleting `tmp/tmux-1000` directory, and then installing tmux again. It seemed to me that tmux was using the `default` file present in `tmp/tmux-1000` directory every time it was being started and very importantly this directory is not being deleted on uninstalling `tmux`

Comment: This started to be a problem for me after an upgrade of tmux. I resolved it by removing a directory called `/tmp/tmux-501`, which was recreated after launching tmux again